# Customize axes in plotly.js for categorical data with missing points

Tags: javascript, charts, plotly, plotly.js

I have a set of data basically from node-edge graph: a number of nodes (from A1...A10) and a list of edges (i.e. A1-A3, A2-A3, A4-A6 etc.). I want to create a bubble chart from this data, however, if I simply pass my edges as points I end up with axes reduced to nodes with edges (if A5 does not have edges, it will not show) and Y axis is sorted depending on the first edge point, not alphabetically (if A3 was in the first edge, it will be first on the Y axis). What I am looking for is to manually pass list of nodes (A1...A10) to plotly.js to build identical X and Y axes. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Found a suitable solution in [Plotly.js: Cannot show full categorical x-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44490998/plotly-js-cannot-show-full-categorical-x-axis)

```
var layout = {
         xaxis: {
             title: 'x Axis Label'
             , autorange: false
             , type: 'category'
             , categoryorder: 'array'
             , categoryarray: ['0001','0002','0003']
         },
         yaxis: {
             title: 'Y Axis Label  %>'
             , autorange: false
             , type: 'category'
             , categoryorder: 'array'
             , categoryarray: ['one','two','three', 'etc']
         },
    };
```

However, still had to use `autorange: true` otherwise it would not display initial graph correctly